# Datepicker Maxdate variable issue

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem with maxDate value in ngbDatepicker :

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input class="form-control inputs2" formControlName="bdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
    [minDate]="{year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1}" [maxDate]="todaymax2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

todaymax2 value is :

```
public year = new Date().getFullYear();
  public month = new Date().getMonth();
  public day = new Date().getDate();
  public todaymax2 = '{year: '+ this.year +', month: '+this.month+', day: '+this.day+'}';
```

everything is ok i got these values :

```
maxDate : {year: 2019, month: 9, day: 29}
minDate : {year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1}
```

minDate is ok but not maxDate.

Someone have an answer ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made `todaymax2` a string by adding `''`

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9wrkzj?embed=1&file=app/datepicker-multiple.ts)**

```
public todaymax2 = {year:  this.year , month: this.month, day: this.day}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks ! In my case i had to add +1 to month ^^